# about cloudfoundry and openshift

Tags: openshift, cloud-foundry

I want to build my own pass platform based on cloudfoundry and openshift. I want to use some of the functions of these two platforms, and I don't want to deploy them all in the environment. Is this feasible? What similar open source projects can learn from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me produce some contents about `OpenShift` for you as follows.

[OpenShift Online](https://www.openshift.com/products/online/) : Free plan is enough to your first training.

[OpenShift HandsOn training](https://learn.openshift.com/) : Awesome practical training, it need not to prepare your env.

[OpenShift Documentation - Enterprise](https://docs.openshift.com/) and [OpenShift OpenSource AKA OKD - Documentation](https://www.okd.io/)

If you'd like to deploy to your on-premise as open source project of `OpenShift`, you can review/test/operate the `OKD` (former name: `OpenShift Origin`).

I hope if help you. :^)

Comment: I don't want to use all of them, just want to use some of the components, use some of them, build my own pass, do you think it works?

Comment: If you are going to build your own PaaS, why use them at all as they provide their own PaaS functionality. If you want to go to all the extra effort of building your own PaaS, rather than using what is supplied, you are perhaps better off dropping down to just Kubernetes. Building your own PaaS is going to be a lot of work though. OpenShift/OKD is going to provide a much quicker solution. So what exactly is it about OpenShift PaaS you don't like or think you need.

Comment: Because some functions require us to develop ourselves, such as authentication services, to apply to our own environment, I now think that these two pass platforms are too bloated, so I don't want to deploy all of their components to the environment for the time being. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to Cloud Foundry, it is just a collection of services. We use Bosh to deploy Cloud Foundry, which knows how to deploy all the services so that they can talk to each other & function cohesively. There's nothing that would prevent you from using a different Bosh configuration (or even totally different tool) to deploy these services in a different way.

You can run projects like Gorouter, UAA, Cloud Controller and Garden stand-alone. The individual project sites typically have instructions for doing this.

Ex:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter#start
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa#quick-start

Other components might be a little trickier as they depend on each other. Diego, for example, depends on Garden and is built to send logs through Loggregator. In these cases, you might need to do a little work if you didn't want to use one of the dependent components.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-design-notes#what-are-all-these-repos-and-what-do-they-do

I would disagree with your comment about these systems being bloated, and say that depends on your perspective. If you don't need a lot of the features, then I could see why you might think that. I'd say overkill might be a better way to put it though.

If you don't need all the functionality that PaaS platforms provide, you could look at other options: Dokku, Kubernetes, Knative, etc... You don't get all the features of CF, but the systems have smaller footprints. If you can live without the extra features, then these might be better options for you.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped me a lot.